# I want the website inside the loadURL to go back when I press the backspace key

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm writing an electron app. I used loadURL to show a website inside my app. I want the website inside the loadURL to go back when I press the backspace key. The Official documentary on loadURL was not helpful for me. How do I make the loadUrl content go back when the backspace is pressed,please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use globalshortcuts and webContents.goBack( ) to do this.
For eg :

```
const { app, globalShortcut, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

app.on('ready', () => {

let win = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 1500 })
win.loadURL('http://github.com')

let contents = win.webContents

// Register a 'backspace' shortcut listener.
const ret = globalShortcut.register('Backspace', () => {
console.log('Backspace is pressed');
contents.goBack();
})

if (!ret) {
console.log('registration failed')
}

// Check whether a shortcut is registered.
console.log(globalShortcut.isRegistered('Backspace'))
})

app.on('will-quit', () => {
// Unregister a shortcut.
globalShortcut.unregister('Backspace')

// Unregister all shortcuts.
globalShortcut.unregisterAll()
})
```